# XSL - Increment position in for each based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to count the position based on if attribute has a value or not. Given the example below. Please help

Input:

```
<data>
    <posts>
        <entry a="1" />
        <entry a="1" />
        <entry a="2" />
        <entry  />
        <entry a="1" />
        <entry a="1" />
    </posts>
</data>
```

Xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <posts>
            <xsl:for-each select="data/posts/entry">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <xsl:if test="@a">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('$i = ', $i)"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </posts>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output xml:

```
<posts>
  <entry>$i = 1</entry>
  <entry>$i = 2</entry>
  <entry>$i = 3</entry>
  <entry>$i = 5</entry>
  <entry>$i = 6</entry>
</posts>
```

Expected output xml:

```
<posts>
  <entry>$i = 1</entry>
  <entry>$i = 2</entry>
  <entry>$i = 3</entry>
  <entry>$i = 4</entry>
  <entry>$i = 5</entry>
</posts>
```

I dont want position to count if the attribute is not present.I am new to xsl's, excuse if I have done any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:-

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <posts>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/posts/entry[@a]">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('$i = ', $i)"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </posts>
</xsl:template>
```